# Flag if value occurs more than once per month - group by if statement in DAX PowerBI

Tags: if-statement, group-by, powerbi, dax

I have the following example data.

```
 YYYY_MM    Reg    Test
 2019_01    ABC     1
 2019_01    ABC     0
 2019_01    DFG     0
 2019_02    ABC     0
 2019_02    ABC     0
 2019_02    DFG     0
 2019_02    DFG     1
 2019_02    DFG     1
 2019_02    DFG     0
 2019_02    HIJ     0
```

I want to flag and Reg within each unique YYYY_MM where test = 1 one or more times that month. Hence the final data set would look as follows.

```
 YYYY_MM    Reg    Test    Flag
 2019_01    ABC     1       1
 2019_01    ABC     0       1
 2019_01    DFG     0       0
 2019_02    ABC     0       0
 2019_02    ABC     0       0
 2019_02    DFG     0       1
 2019_02    DFG     1       1 
 2019_02    DFG     1       1
 2019_02    DFG     0       1
 2019_02    HIJ     0       0
```

I was thinking of using the GROUPBY function or SUMMARIZE but am not totally sure how to use them for what I need it to do. Happy to go in a totally different direction though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume that you need this flag as a calculated column, and that your table name is "Data".

Create a column:

```
Flag =
VAR Total_Test =
    CALCULATE ( SUM ( Data[Test] ), ALLEXCEPT ( Data, Data[YYYY_MM], Data[Reg] ) )
RETURN
    IF ( Total_Test > 0, 1, 0 )
```

Result:

[image]

How it works:
We use ALLEXCEPT to group data. We sum up all values for column test, but keep filters on columns yyyy-mm and Reg.Store result in a variable, and then perform a logical test.